# Why would we use two servers for one website

Tags: php

I am relatively new to Web development. I was reading about Remote files in PHP, and I came across this question at
[Quara](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-store-data-in-a-JSON-file-on-a-remote-server)

My question is why would we require to use a second server in general?

Comment: If I had to guess I would say in part because you link to some outside place. That link could go dead some day and this question becomes useless. You may want to edit to explain why you are confused and reference quotes or summarize what that article said that was confusing. In short though - a CDN comes to mind first. A processing server. Read/write, staging, static, etc. There are numerous reasons why you could do so. Require is not a good word to use in general.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that your question is to broad and opinion based. There are rules on a good question, and you need to be more specific. That being said, i did not down vote you. But I have seen that before. It is part of the stackoverflow guidelines. Also, you can use servers for data security, scaling, optimization, to name a few

Comment: In general , you use the second server because the first server can't serve by it's own. it's called [horizontal scaling](https://blog.digitalocean.com/horizontally-scaling-php-applications/) ,

Comment: *the downvote button is misused*. Not in this case. The description of the downvote button says *This question shows no research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. You may want to take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, particularly [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask], before asking your next question here.

Comment: Thanks every one for the clarifications and information, and also for your maturity in dealing with "such kind of questions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally multiple servers used for high availability.
Using single server is a bottle nick. If it is goes down, your web will not be available. 
Also multiple servers used to balance the load on each server.